# Как сделать кнопку по ширение input?

Tags: html, css, form

у **input** и  **button** стоит *width: 100%;* так почему же их ширина разная ?

Как сделать кнопку по ширение  **input** и чтобы при изменении ширины экрана **button**  был ровно под размер **input** ?

```css
.form_wapper {
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px 4px #00000047;
    max-width: 243px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 59px 25px 28px;
}

.form_wapper input {
    width: 100%;
}

.form_wapper button {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form_wapper">
  <form>
  
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text"> 
    <button>button</button>
  
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Так он и есть у Вас по ширине экрана. Подсветите кнопку и всё увидите. 
button {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
       Проверил у себя, при изменении размерности экрана - кнопка сохраняет размер соответствующий input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё дело в рамке `border`.
100% берётся в случае `box-sizing:content-box` (в данном случае это значение выставлено по умолчанию) от размера содержимого а рамка накидывается поверх, что и даёт дополнительный размер.
Исправляем выставляя `box-sizing: border-box;` к стилю `input`. 
Таким образом размеры 100% будет считаться вместе с рамкой и ничего за границу вылезать уже не будет.

```css
.form_wapper {
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px 4px #00000047;
    max-width: 243px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 59px 25px 28px;
}

.form_wapper input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;  // Добавили
}

.form_wapper button {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form_wapper">
  <form>
  
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text"> 
    <button>button</button>
  
  </form>
</div>
```

Но я предлагаю воспользоваться более идеологически правильным способом, так что бы не зависеть от `border` и неочевидного поведения `100%`, сделать решения на основе `flex-box` который по сути и предназначен для решения подобных задач.

```css
.form_wapper {
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 4px #00000047;
  max-width: 243px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 59px 25px 28px;
}

.form_wapper .form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form_wapper button {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form_wapper">
  <form class="form">

    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <button>button</button>

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо для `input` добавить `box-sizing: border-box;`

Пример

```css
.form_wapper {
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 4px #00000047;
  max-width: 243px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 59px 25px 28px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form_wapper input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form_wapper button {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form_wapper">
  <form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <button>button</button>
  </form>
</div>
```